# How can I change keyframe state in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, keyframe

I want to change a keyframe state dynamiclly with JQuery.
Here's my keyframe:

```
@keyframes moveItUp {
    10% {
        top: 18%;
    }
    20% {
        top: 16%;
    }
    30% {
        top: 14%;
    }
    40% {
        top: 12%;
    }
    50% {
        top: 10%;
    }
    60% {
        top: 8%;
    }
    70% {
        top: 6%;
    }
    80% {
        top: 4%;
    }
    90% {
        top: 2%;
    }
    100% {
        top: -20px;
    }
}
```

For example, I want to switch from 20% to 40% ect.. dynamiclly with Javascript

How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but since the style changes between `10%` and `90%` are uniform, you can remove the keyframes in between and simplify your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [a great blog article on MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msdn_answers/2013/11/04/part-i-using-javascript-to-set-keyframes-in-css-animations-windows-store-apps-ie/) that explains exactly how to do this.

```
  var rule;    
  var ss = document.styleSheets;

  for (var i = 0; i < ss.length; ++i) {

      // loop through all the rules!
      for (var x = 0; x < ss[i].cssRules.length; ++x) {

          rule = ss[i].cssRules[x];
          if (rule.name == "moveItUp" && rule.type == CSSRule.KEYFRAMES_RULE) {

              // do what you need to do here
          }
      }
  }
```