# How to access and print CSS3 @keyframes scales and corresponding styles inside them through javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

```
.line3 {
width: 300px;
height: 2px;
border-radius: 5%;
animation: line 60s infinite;
}

@keyframes line {
0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
100%{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

I want to access the values inside the @keyframes through javascript and print them to the document.

Comment: Similar Questios: [get @keyframe current value in css3 with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426306/get-keyframe-current-value-in-css3-with-javascript) [How can I change keyframe state in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227403/how-can-i-change-keyframe-state-in-javascript)

Comment: Also see [Accessing Keyframes Through JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919816/accessing-keyframes-through-js) – in short, it's not possible

Comment: @Xander The response that you link is wrong. See the MSDN link in one of the answers linked by TheViralGriffin